Firebase Admin SDK can't be used with FirebaseAuth
An issue i encountered with Firebase admin SDK and Firebase Authentication  while trying to create an user managment system in my android app.
So that user managment supposed to be active when admin account is logged in app.
Otherwise when user is logged in user managment system supposed to be inactive.
When i tried to implement Firebase Admin SDK with Firebase Authentication in my build.gradle file.
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

Firebase Authentication ovetwrites some libs and i unnable to get list of all users. If i remove dependency  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1' ,i'll be unable to use FirebaseUser
public List<FirebaseUser> getUsers() throws FirebaseAuthException {
        FirebaseAuth auth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        List<FirebaseUser> users =  auth1.getUsers(uids);
        return users;
    }

But IDEA can't recognize admin SDK's method.


When you're using the following dependency:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'

It means that you're trying to use the Firebase Authentication client SDK and not the Firebase Admin SDK, which is a set of server libraries that lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments.
If you want to integrate your own servers with Firebase Authentication then I recommend you use Admin Auth API.
When it comes to the client SDK, please note that the FirebaseAuth class doesn't contain any .getUsers() method, hence that error. On the other hand, the Firebase Admin SDK allows retrieving a list of users using a method called .getUsersAsync().
So, please choose the service that is more appropriate for the use case of your app, don't mix them because these two services serve different purposes.
P.S. When you're using:
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')

There is no need to specify the version of the Auth, it can simply be:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

Edit:
As far as I understand you need to manage your users. Please note the docs explicitly say that:

The admin user management API gives you the ability to programmatically complete the following tasks from a secure server environment.

Not the client.

I have to use both of services in my app. Because if i logging in admin account, app will provide ability to manage other's user accounts. But if not, user won't have ability to manage other's user accounts. Is that possible to realize? Or i have to use Firebase Console to manage accounts in my Firebase Authentication?
